# angular 8 how to pass parent class value to child class

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I want to assign value data to buyer.cnic, buyer.name and buyer.phone.
the values I get are {sCommercial: true
​
marla: "12"
​
totalAmount: "0121233123"
​
}

```js
export class AddDhaFile {
  buyer: Buyer[];
  dealNumber?: string;
  marla: number;
  isCommercial: boolean;
  totalAmount: number;
  payments?: Payment[];
  constructor(value: any) {
    this.marla = value.marla;
    this.isCommercial = value.isCommercial;
    this.totalAmount = value.totalAmount;
  }
}

export class Buyer {
  name: string;
  cnic: string;
  phone: string;
  constructor(value: any) {
    this.name = value.name;

    this.cnic = value.cnic;
    this.phone = value.phone;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from parent to child you can do it in 3 ways.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
Here is the link on how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the value object looks like this.

```
value = {
isCommercial: true,
​marla: "12",
​totalAmount: "0121233123"​,
buyer: {name: 'xyx' , cnic: 'some digits', phone:'0900 78601'}
}


export class AddDhaFile {
  buyer: Buyer[];
  dealNumber?: string;
  marla: number;
  isCommercial: boolean;
  totalAmount: number;
  payments?: Payment[];
  constructor(value: any) {
    this.marla = value.marla;
    this.isCommercial = value.isCommercial;
    this.totalAmount = value.totalAmount;
    this.buyer.append(new Buyer(value.buyer))
  }
}
```

OR if value object looks like this.

```
value = {
isCommercial: true,
​marla: "12",
​totalAmount: "0121233123"​,
buyers: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
}

export class AddDhaFile {
  buyer: Buyer[];
  dealNumber?: string;
  marla: number;
  isCommercial: boolean;
  totalAmount: number;
  payments?: Payment[];
  constructor(value: any) {
    this.marla = value.marla;
    this.isCommercial = value.isCommercial;
    this.totalAmount = value.totalAmount;
    this.buyer = value.buyers.map(buyer => new Buyer(buyer)))
  }
}
```